# Show that $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{2\sin\theta}{2\sin\theta-1}$

Tags: calculus, parametric

Parametric equation of curve is $ x=2\sin\theta +\cos(2\theta) $ , $y=1+\cos(2\theta)$ , for $0\leq\theta\leq\pi/2$

Show that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{2\sin\theta}{2\sin\theta-1}$$
I drived $x$ and $y$ seperatly for $x$,

$$ x=2\cos\theta+\sin\theta\pm\sin\theta$$ and for the

derivative of $y$ i got $y=-2\sin(2\theta)$

and then I did

$$dy/dx= y=-2\sin(2\theta), \qquad   x=2\cos\theta+\sin\theta\pm \sin\theta$$

but I dont know if I did it wronge or I don't know how to continue. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Derivative of $\cos 2\theta$ is $-2\sin 2\theta$ like you wrote for $y'$. But you did it wrong in $x'$.

Comment: @Math Lover i did that.

Comment: But you did the same thing wrong for $x'$. You did correct for $y'$.

Comment: @Math Lover How? i used the product rule. and derived.

Comment: $x' = 2 \cos \theta - 2 \sin 2 \theta = 2 \cos \theta (1 - 2 \sin \theta)$.

Comment: @Math Lover how did you get that?

Comment: $x = 2\sin\theta +\cos(2\theta), x' = 2 \frac{d (\sin \theta)}{d\theta} + \frac{d (\cos 2\theta)}{d\theta}$

Comment: @Math Lover what is d stand for ?

Comment: The question asks you to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$. So how are your proceeding with it if you do not understand what $d$ stands for? Also I see now that you asked a question previously which has answered it and you have accepted the answer. Did you accept the answer without understanding it? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016437/parametric-equation-of-curve-is-x-2-sin-theta-cos2-theta-y-1-cos2-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{d\theta}/\frac{dx}{d\theta}=\frac{-2\sin 2\theta}{2\cos \theta-2\sin 2 \theta}=\frac{-\sin \theta \cos \theta}{\cos \theta(1-2\sin \theta)}=\frac{\sin \theta}{2\sin \theta-1}.$$

Comment: how did you go from 2cos−2sin2 to cos(1−2sin).?

Comment: Because $\sin 2\theta=2\sin \theta \cos \theta$.

Comment: Thank you do you happen to know how to find the points on the curve where dy/dx is =0

Answer (score 3):

You need to make use of the Chain Rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule.

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{d\theta} \frac{d\theta}{dx}$.

The first term on the RHS is simple to calculate since you have been given $y$ as a function of $\theta$ but the second term requires a bit more attention. You have been given $x(\theta)$ and you want to get $\frac{d\theta}{dx}$.

$x = x(\theta)$

$\implies \frac{d(x)}{dx} = \frac{d(x(\theta))}{dx}$

$\implies \frac{d(x)}{dx} = \frac{d(x(\theta))}{d\theta} \frac{d\theta}{dx}$

$ \therefore \frac{d\theta}{dx} = \frac{1}{\frac{d(x(\theta))}{d\theta}}$

Apply these steps and also be mindful of you trigonometric identities. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{dy/d \theta}{dx/d \theta}=\frac{-2\sin 2\theta}{2 \cos \theta-2\sin 2\theta}$$

Let $ \sin \theta =s, \cos \theta= c\;$
We have

$$ \dfrac{2\cdot-2 sc }{2c-2\cdot 2\cdot sc }=\dfrac{s}{2s-1}$$